# I am showing html on page with Ajax. I want the added css not to affect the whole page

Tags: html, css, scope, styles

I'm adding html with Ajax into the div.
However, the  field in the incoming data affects the entire page. I just want it to work inside that div.
ajax data =>

```
var data =  [
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "htmldata": "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\"><style><!--\r\n/* Font Definitions */\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Segoe UI\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 11 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Segoe UI Semibold\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 11 7 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;}\r\n/* Style Definitions */\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tmso-fareast-language:EN-US;}\r\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{mso-style-priority:99;\r\n\tcolor:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\r\nspan.E-postaStili18\r\n\t{mso-style-type:personal-compose;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#662D91;\r\n\tfont-weight:normal;\r\n\tfont-style:normal;\r\n\ttext-decoration:none none;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\r\n\tfont-size:10.0pt;}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;\r\n\tmargin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\r\n<o:shapedefaults v:ext=\"edit\" spidmax=\"1026\" />\r\n</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\r\n<o:shapelayout v:ext=\"edit\">\r\n<o:idmap v:ext=\"edit\" data=\"1\" />\r\n</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=\"TR\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word\"><div class=\"WordSection1\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#662D91\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:#5F5F5F\">________________________________________________________________________________</span> <o:p></o:p></p></div><div><div style=\"margin-top:18.0pt;margin-bottom:15.0pt\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\">Microsoft Teams toplantısı</span><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\"> <o:p></o:p></span></p></div><div style=\"margin-bottom:15.0pt\"><div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><b><span style=\"font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\">Bilgisayarınızda veya mobil uygulamanızda katılın</span></b><b><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\"> <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\"><a href=\"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_MGRmM…%2c%22Oid%22%2343a%220ba952d6-f186-4885-8cca-50b5050a4936%22%7d\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI Semibold&quot;,sans-serif;color:#6264A7\">Toplantıya katılmak için buraya tıklayın</span></a> <o:p></o:p></span></p></div><div style=\"margin-top:15.0pt;margin-bottom:18.0pt\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:#252424\"><a href=\"https://aka.ms/JoinTeamsMeeting\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"font-size:10.5pt;color:#6264A7\">Daha Fazla Bilgi Edinin</span></a> | <a href=\"https://teams.microsoft.com/meetingOptions/?organizer234Id=0ba9…2E5ZDU2340OTUxOWZl@thread.v2&amp;messageId=0&amp;language=tr-TR\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"font-size:10.5pt;color:#6264A7\">Toplantı seçenekleri</span></a> <o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:#5F5F5F\">________________________________________________________________________________</span> <o:p></o:p></p></div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#662D91\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p></div></body></html>"
  }
]

=>> 

<style><!--\r\n/* Font Definitions */\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Segoe UI\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 11 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Segoe UI Semibold\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 11 7 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;}\r\n/* Style Definitions */\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tmso-fareast-language:EN-US;}\r\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{mso-style-priority:99;\r\n\tcolor:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\r\nspan.E-postaStili18\r\n\t{mso-style-type:personal-compose;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:#662D91;\r\n\tfont-weight:normal;\r\n\tfont-style:normal;\r\n\ttext-decoration:none none;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\r\n\tfont-size:10.0pt;}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;\r\n\tmargin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n--></style>
```

=> jquery

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "get",
            data: {
            },
            beforeSend: function () { 
            },
            success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            
            $("#zxc123").append(`
                <div style="border:10px solid red; margin-bottom:20px">${response.data[i].htmldata}</div>         
            `)
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
          });
```

=> html

```
<a>Test<a>
<div id="zxc123"></div>
```

Comment: There is no way people are going to try to decipher what is going on within that huge string of data but as a workaround have you considered using an iframe?

Comment: I don't want to use iframes so as not to disturb the usual flow. In vue js, style elements can be given scope property, but html does not support this property except firefox.